# Request AFNetworking with json and header in swift 3.2

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

```
let header = [
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "X-Source":"iOS",
            "Authorization":token]
let strURL = "ValidURL"


let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
let serializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()
    for (_,dict) in header.enumerated() {
        serializer.setValue("\(dict.value)", forHTTPHeaderField: "\(dict.key)")
    }
    manager.requestSerializer = serializer

   let req = serializer.request(withMethod: "POST", urlString: strURL, parameters: params, error: nil)
   manager.dataTask(with: req as URLRequest) { (response, data, error) in
        print(error)
        print(response)
        print(data)
    }
//No response from this method
```

**Also, I tried:**

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: strURL)!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
for (_,dict) in header.enumerated() {
        request.setValue("\(dict.value)", forHTTPHeaderField: "\(dict.key)")
    }
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
manager.dataTask(with: request) { (response, data, error) in
     print(error)
     print(response)
     print(data)
}
```

**Even I have tried:**

```
manager.post(strURL, parameters: params, progress: nil, success: { (sessionTask, respose) in
            if let dict = respose as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
                print(dict)
            } else {
            }
        }) { (task, error) in
            print(error)
        }

//It Give me: failed: bad request (400)
```

Comment: In the first two versions, the result of dataTask is a task that should have `resume()` called on it

Comment: @LouFranco thanks but no luck after resume `"Unable to process JSON"`

Comment: Reference to `https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking`, in the section of Request Serialization, that what you want.

Comment: "Unable to process JSON" probably refers to params. What is it?

Comment: are you sure you have AFnetworking imported in this file?

Comment: @Lu_ Yes i am sure!

Comment: @LouFranco You are right !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here

1. When you use a dataTask method, you get back a task object. You need to call `resume()` on it when you want the request to be sent.
2. Your errors indicate that your JSON body is incorrect. That is in your `params` object which probably does not match what the service is expecting.